# Why are there `jupyter lab` and `jupyter-lab` commands in my environment?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

The two commands seem to have the same functionality, so why do they both exist in my environment?

Is this because:

- I have accidentally installed two duplicate programs.
- They are aliases just for convenience.

Or is there any other reason?

###### Command outputs:

`which jupyter` outputs: `/opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter`

`which jupyter-lab` outputs: `/opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter-lab`

Comment: Have you compared `jupyter lab -h` and `jupyter-lab -h`?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes. They output the same. By the way these commands with `--version` output the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.